# Can't switch between audio devices

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS.

Can't find a way to switch my audio devices properly. I have a USB mixer (Behringer Q802USB) and the laptop's speaker. In Pulse Audio Volume Control the only audio output avaliable is "jack in (pulse out)". If I try to change the hardware output directly from Ubuntu Studio Controls>Audio Setup>Jack Master Settings>Jack Master Device, it just go back to the USB device automatically. I tryed change the hardware device from Qjackctl as well, it asks to restart, then back to the USB device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the output device option in settings?

This might help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioControls

Comment: don't have this on ubuntu studio